# Проверка переменной на валидность PHP

Tags: php

Есть динамическая переменная $password в которой храниться генерируемый пароль
допустим:

```
$password="BLKoAyZ9";
function testPassword() {
$test=null;
$test=//проверка $password на валидность
return $test // нужно чтобы возвращала true или false
};
```

Требования к паролю:
Миниму 6 букв
Минимум 2 цифры
Минимум 1 спецсимвол. т.е - (!@#$%^&&*_+)
можно ли реализовать проверку чтобы функция возвращала true или false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имеем две строки для теста:

```
$password_1 = 's3xbl4y@t';
$password_2 = 'test$';
```

И следующую функцию:

```
function check_password ($pass)
{
    if (strlen($pass) >= 9)
    {
        $number = preg_match_all('/[0-9]/', $pass);
        $letter = preg_match_all('/[A-Za-z]/', $pass);
        $symbol = preg_match_all('/[!@#$%^&*_+]/', $pass);

        if ($letter >= 6 && $symbol >= 1 && $number >= 2)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Делаем дамп для проверки функции:

```
var_dump(check_password($password_1), check_password($password_2));
```

На выходе мы получаем:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Comment: 1. `'/[!@#$%^&*_+]/'` 
2. `preg_match()` _(без _all)_

Comment: @Эдуард, пробовали без `all`? Спасибо за первое, исправлю сейчас)

Answer (score 2):

```
// Проверка политик пароля
if (!preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $password)) {
     // Отсутствуют буквы верхнего регистра
}
if (!preg_match('/[a-z]/', $password)) {
    // Отсутствуют буквы нижнего регистра
}
if (!preg_match('/[0-9]/', $password)) {
    // Отсутствуют цифры
}
if (!preg_match("/[,.<>\\/?;:'\"[\\]\\{\\}\\\\|`~!@#$%^&*()_+=-]/", $password)) {
    // Отсутствуют знаки препинания
}
```

Comment: а что если допустим есть буквы (в верхнем и в нижнем регистре), цифры
но меньше чем необзодимо т.е букв меньше 6 или цифр меньше 2х

Comment: @НиколайВасиленков, написал ответ, думаю вам подойдет.

Comment: [A-Z].*[A-Z].*[A-Z] проверка не менее 3-х больших букв в разных местах строки, например

Comment: Или то же самое ([A-Z].*){3,}